# Typescript - create type of all available css properties

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-in-js

I'm using React and Styled Components and I have a function that accepts a string of a css attribute. I want to type it to validate that the string is a valid css attribute (color, background-color, etc...)

```
function doSomething(cssPropertyName: SomeType) {
}

doSomething('border-color'); // No error
doSomething('non-existing-css-property'); // Should give an error
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Ref: This maybe? https://github.com/frenic/csstype, with `(prop: keyof CSSProperties) => ...` Though you'd need to provide `borderColor` instead of `border-color` (for example).

Comment: Yes! That's the stuff. I'm good with the camel case. Do you want to add this as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With: https://github.com/frenic/csstype I think you can simply use:

```
function doSomething(prop: keyof CSSProperties) {
}

doSomething('borderColor'); // No error
doSomething('non-existing-css-property'); // Should give an error
```